# Why doesn't Perl's Try::Tiny's try/catch give me the same results as eval?

Tags: perl, eval, try-catch

Why doesn't the subroutine with try/catch give me the same results as the eval-version does?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings; use strict;
use 5.012;
use Try::Tiny;

sub shell_command_1 {
    my $command = shift;
    my $timeout_alarm = shift;
    my @array;
    eval {
        local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "timeout '$command'\n" };
        alarm $timeout_alarm;
        @array = qx( $command );
        alarm 0;
    };
    die $@ if $@ && $@ ne "timeout '$command'\n";
    warn $@ if $@ && $@ eq "timeout '$command'\n";
    return @array;
}
shell_command_1( 'sleep 4', 3 );
say "Test_1";

sub shell_command_2 {
    my $command = shift;
    my $timeout_alarm = shift;
    my @array;
    try {
        local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "timeout '$command'\n" };
        alarm $timeout_alarm;
        @array = qx( $command );
        alarm 0;
    }
    catch {
    die $_ if $_ ne "timeout '$command'\n";
    warn $_ if $_ eq "timeout '$command'\n";
    }
    return @array;
}
shell_command_2( 'sleep 4', 3 );
say "Test_2"
```

Comment: Remember to include the result that you are getting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are missing the final semicolon on the try/catch blocks.

You have:

```
try  {
    ...
}
catch {
    ...
}
return;
```

So, you have code that is equivalent to: `try( CODEREF, catch( CODEREF, return ) );`

**Update:**

I forgot to mention, to fix your code simply change `shell_command_2`:

```
sub shell_command_2 {
    my $command = shift;
    my $timeout_alarm = shift;
    my @array;
    try {
        local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "timeout '$command'\n" };
        alarm $timeout_alarm;
        @array = qx( $command );
        alarm 0;
    }
    catch {
        die $_ if $_ ne "timeout '$command'\n";
        warn $_ if $_ eq "timeout '$command'\n";
    };           # <----- Added ; here <======= <======= <======= <=======
    return @array;
}
```