# Not sure I'm using Perl's Try::Tiny correctly

Tags: perl, scope, try-catch, eval

I'm new to using objects, and don't understand why [Try::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Try-Tiny-0.11/lib/Try/Tiny.pm) won't `catch` the errors in my `try` statements. Here is a sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
use strict;  
use warnings;
use Net::FTP;
use Try::Tiny;

my $TIMEOUT = 5;
my $HOST = 'replace_with_hostname';
my $USER = 'replace_with_username';
my $PASS = 'replace_with_password';
my @ERRORS;
my $ftp = undef;

sub my_sub {
  my $err = shift;
  push(@ERRORS,$err);
  goto END;
}

try {
  local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "new\n" };
  alarm $TIMEOUT;
  $ftp = Net::FTP->new($HOST, Passive=>1, DEBUG=>3, Timeout=>2);
  alarm 0;
}
catch {
  die $_ if $_ ne "new\n"; 
  my_sub("FTP: cannot connect to [$HOST]");
};

try {
  local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "login\n" };
  alarm $TIMEOUT;
  $ftp->login($USER,$PASS);
  alarm 0;
}
catch {
  die $_ if $_ ne "login\n"; 
  my_sub("FTP: cannot cannot log in");
};

END: {
  if (@ERRORS) {
    print "$ERRORS[0]\n";
    exit -1;
  }
  print "Success\n";
  exit 0;
}
```

I'm using the `goto` function because I'll eventually have blocks for WebDAV and CMIS tests, and want to capture all of the errors before I hit `END`. I can make the preceding do what I want by changing the `try-catch` blocks like so:

```
try {
  local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "new\n" };
  alarm $TIMEOUT;
  $ftp = Net::FTP->new($HOST, Passive=>1, DEBUG=>3, Timeout=>2) 
    or my_sub("FTP: cannot connect to [$HOST]");
  alarm 0;
}
catch {
  die $_ if $_ ne "new\n"; 
};
```

However, in both cases, I have the feeling I'm not using [Try::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Try-Tiny-0.11/lib/Try/Tiny.pm) well.

And of course, what I'd really like to do is put the `try-catch` blocks in a function, just like [sid_com did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871619/why-doesnt-perls-trytinys-try-catch-give-me-the-same-results-as-eval). That doesn't work for me:

```
sub try_f {
  my $cmd = shift;
  my $msg = shift;
  try {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "timeout '$cmd'\n" };
    alarm $TIMEOUT;
    \$cmd or my_sub($msg);
    alarm 0;
  }
  catch {
    die $_ if $_ ne "timeout '$cmd'\n"; 
  };
} # sub

try_f("$ftp = Net::FTP->new(Host=>$HOST, Passive=>1)", "FTP: cannot connect to [$HOST]");

try_f("$ftp->login($USER,$PASS)", "FTP: cannot cannot log in");
```

The error says `$ftp` is an uninitialized value, but I don't know how to get around that.

EDIT: Here's the working synthesis of the two answers I received. Thanks, Max and LeoNerd!

```
use strict;  
use warnings;
use Net::FTP;
use Try::Tiny;

my $HOST = 'replace_with_hostname';
my $USER = 'replace_with_username';
my $PASS = 'replace_with_password';
my @ERRORS;
my $ftp = undef;

sub try_f {
  my $timeout = shift;
  my $command = shift;
  my $message = shift;
  my $label   = shift;
  try {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "timeout\n" };
    alarm $timeout;
    $command->() or die "module\n";
    alarm 0;
  }
  catch {
    if ( $_ eq "module\n" || $_ eq "timeout\n" ) {
      push(@ERRORS,"$message: $_");
      goto $label;
    }
    die $_;
  };
}

FTP_BLOCK: {
  try_f(4, sub { $ftp = Net::FTP->new($HOST, Passive=>1, Debug=>3) }, "FTP: cannot connect to [$HOST]", 'END');
  try_f(2, sub { $ftp->login($USER,$PASS) }, "FTP: cannot log in", 'END');
}

END: {
  if (@ERRORS) {
    foreach my $e (@ERRORS) { print "$e"; }
    exit -1;
  }
  print "Success\n";
  exit 0;
}
```

Comment: That is a lot of code for me to read.

Comment: Good feedback. I'll work on putting in only the essential info.

Comment: The only way to win is to not play.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Net::FTP->new`](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/libnet-1.22/Net/FTP.pm#CONSTRUCTOR) doesn't `die` on error.  Instead, it simply returns `undef`.  Because of this, `Try::Tiny` isn't able to determine something went wrong, and the `catch` block isn't executed.

Instead of `my_sub`, use

```
$ftp = Net::FTP->new($HOST, Passive=>1, DEBUG=>3, Timeout=>2) or die $@;
```

The Try::Tiny docs say that `$@` won't have the error **in the `catch` block**, but `Net::FTP->new` says it will put an error message there if it returns `undef`.  Which is why you can `die` with that message **in the `try` block** (you could also use your own message in that case, if desired).

Likewise, `login` [returns a *false* value on error](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/libnet-1.22/Net/FTP.pm#METHODS), so you'll need to add an "`or die`" statement (unfortunately, `login` does not appear to give an error message on error).

Comment: Great, the `try-catch` block works now. I'm using `die "bad\n";` and then calling `my_sub()` from the catch when `$_` is either `bad\n` or `new\n`. PS, I'd upvote, but I'm too noob to do so. :-(

Comment: I made a statement about the exception from the signal handler not being caught by `catch`.  It turns out I was misspelling `$SIG{ALRM}`.  Once I spelled it correctly, `catch` caught the exception.

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to pass code around in strings:

```
try_f("$ftp = Net::FTP->new(Host=>$HOST, Passive=>1)", "FTP: cannot connect to [$HOST]");

\$cmd or my_sub($msg);
```

That's not going to work.

Might I suggest instead using `sub { }` to create an anonymous code reference?

```
try_f( sub { $ftp = ..... } );
```

then later

```
$cmd->() or my_sub($msg);
```

Comment: I'm going to be hanging out here a lot more

Comment: Thanks, LeoNerd, this works perfectly. Also, now I've got another Perl nugget in my bag...I don't learn these things unless I've got something concrete to do, so I really appreciate the help you and others contribute here. For the next guy: I found [this helpful post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834590/why-would-i-use-perl-anonymous-subroutines-instead-of-a-named-one) about anonymous subs (and other goodies).